# How to echo using telnet

Tags: python, sockets

I created an echo server that listens for incoming connections and echos any received data. I am using telnet to establish the connection.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import sys

# Create socket
sockfd = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Port for socket and Host
PORT = 8001
HOST = 'localhost'

# bind the socket to host and port
sockfd.bind((HOST, PORT))
# become a server socket
sockfd.listen(5)

while True:
    # Establish and accept connections woth client
    (clientsocket, address) = sockfd.accept()

    print("Got connection from", address)
    # Recieve message from the client
    message = clientsocket.recv(1024)
    reply = 'Server output: ' + message.decode('utf-8')
    if not message:
        break
    # Display messags.
    clientsocket.sendall(str.encode(reply))

# Close the connection with the client
clientsocket.close()
```

Currently after I prompted with "server output:  ", it hangs and nothing is echoed back on to the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have the call to `sockfd.accept()` inside your while-loop:

```
while True:
   # Establish and accept connections woth client
   (clientsocket, address) = sockfd.accept()
```

... because of that, after the server receives the first data, it will block again, waiting for another TCP connection.

Move that call to above the `while True:` line and you'll get behavior more in line with your expectations.

Comment: Another quick question. Is the decode() and encode() necessary in this case. I saw it while doing a little research and never fully understood the person. Could I have simply used clientsocket.sendall(message) and got the same behaviour?

Comment: Interesting enough also, it does not seem to echo back the message. It creates a new connection after every character. I'm not able to type a word.

Comment: Sounds like your telnet client is set to character-mode rather than line mode, and that you haven't moved the `accept()` call up out of the loop yet?